# Is there a schema for validating schematron files?

Tags: xsd, schematron

I'm looking for a schema (ideally an XSD) that will validate a schematron schema file i.e. check that the schematron file is correctly formatted.

I've found this schema https://github.com/oxygenxml/sqf/blob/master/schemas/iso-schematron.xsd which in principle is exactly what I want, however I would prefer something that's a little more official (In the header it says its was converted using TRANG, but it doesn't say what it was converted from).

Does anyone know of any official schemas for Schematron or know if this one is any good?

Comment: Most relevant question. Still. Is there a way to transform official "RELAX NG Compact scheme" to XSD? I also like official.

Answer (score 1):

Schematron is now maintained on GitHub. Check out https://github.com/Schematron/schema for RelaxNG Compact scheme - this is all there is. There are no public XSDs... I also created an SVRL XSD https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron/blob/master/ph-schematron/src/main/resources/schemas/svrl.xsd